# Python OpenCV reads video in low quality

Tags: python, video, opencv

I'm trying to write a program that cuts my gameplay clips for me. In order to achieve what I want I need to detect a red "X" (indicates a kill) in the middle of the frame, which is a 12px * 12px region, so I need full quality. While I was debugging I realized that the frames read by OpenCV seemed lower quality than what I see in a video player.

Here is an example:

[This is the "X" I've cut from a video player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bnP7.png)

[This is the "X" that OpenCV read in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcC6v.png)

Both are from the same frame.

Here is the code I was debugging with:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

success, frame = vid.read()
while success:
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    # Pause video
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    # Quit video
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    success, frame = vid.read()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've also checked the width and the height and they seem to be the same as the original video. I'm using OpenCV version 4.2.0. What could cause this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you share the video?

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nw6PjhXzRGju8Jz2PbdeEqq3jVvDGLSU/view?usp=sharing)
This is the video I was testing on.

Comment: it's not accessible!

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nw6PjhXzRGju8Jz2PbdeEqq3jVvDGLSU/view?usp=sharing) Sorry! Try this.

Comment: Are you sure both frames are same?
did you try to extract frames using ffmpeg?

Comment: Yes, both frames are the same. And no I haven't. How to do that?

Comment: Try this:
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 dest_dir/%04d.png

Comment: to install ffmpeg (ubuntu 18.04):
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ffmpeg

Comment: But do you have any idea why it does that?

Comment: I think the problem is not because of the decoding method.

Comment: if the frames are extracted exactly at the same time, maybe the difference is because of the display functions

Comment: I've tested this out. If I write the picture out to a file it still looks low quality. So I wouldn't blame it on the display functions. Also if I read in a picture using imread() it preserves quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The only thing I had to do is to convert the picture to jpeg (for some reason). I used this function to convert it in memory:

```
def convertToJpeg(img):
    result, encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 100])
    return cv2.imdecode(encoded, 1)
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to read the frame from a file and want to change it's resolution, you'd probably want to use the resize method as described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize). This would need to be done inside the loop, right after you read in the frame. It could be something like:

```
resize(ret, Size(width, height), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
```

**Example :**

```
b = cv2.resize(frame,(1280,720),fx=0,fy=0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what i'm looking for. I don't want to resize the picture I want to read it in full quality. By the way I tried what you have suggested and it looks the same. Also my frame size is full HD and the 12px * 12px region in the middle is what I care about.

Comment: Have you tried cap.set(3, 1920);cap.set(4, 1080) this one?? I know this also resize window

Comment: Yes. Nothing changed.